# jQuery selected button, can't get attribute to be alerted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select, this

I'm echoing rows and would like to either delete them or increment them like a thumbs up effect... I can't seem to identify the rows individually.

This is my included jquery source

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

There are no errors in the javascript web console...

This is the click function I'm trying to implement with a test ['clicked']:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(":button").click(function() {
var selectedId = $( this ).attr(id);
alert(selectedId);
alert('clicked');
});
</script>
```

These are my rows which I have echoed:

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'dbconnect.php');

$link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entries";

if ($result = $link->query($query)) {


    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        if($row[0]==0){
        echo "There are no entries.";
        }else {
        $query2 = "SELECT id,saying,date,thumbs_up,comments FROM entries ORDER by ID ASC ";

if (($result = $link->query($query2))) {
    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {

       echo 
       '<div class="primary-container" align="center">'.
       '<div class="entry-container" align="center">'.
       $row[1]." ".
       '</div>'.
       '<div class="bird" align="center">'.
       'Bird Up!'.
       '</div>'.
       '<div class="birdups" align="center">'.
       $row[3].
       '</div>'.
       '<div class="thumbup" align="center">'.
       '<button name="increment" class="button" id="'.$row[0].'">'.
       '<img src="bird_up.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="bird up thumbs up like equivalent thumbnail">'.
       '</button>'.
       '</div>'.
       '</div>'.
       '<br>'
       ;

    }
    }
        }
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **event delegation** for newly added html elements. And you have missed out put the single quotes for id. I hope it solves your issues thanks

```
$(document).on("click" , ".button" , function() {
  var selectedId = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(selectedId);
});
```

Comment: wow. That was perfect! This is my third post asking about this question haha. Thank you JqueryKing <- haha thanks again Monarchy Majesty.

Comment: Worth to mention that you have added quotes arround the `id` (which looks like the actual issue here).

Comment: @ArturFilipiak -  Thanks for notifying